# Custom UISearchBar in navigationItem ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7, styles

I have a customized UISearchBar that I want to display in self.navigationItem.titleView. I have no problem getting it in there and looking the way I want it to but I think something is wrong with how I connect it with UISearchDisplayController.

Here is the UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController in viewDidLoad:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,200.0, 22.0)];
searchBar.barStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
searchBar.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;

searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
```

At this point the search function is not actually working. If I add `[searchDisplayController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];` the search function now works but it messes up all the style I that I had added to `searchBar`.

Edit: Additional information: looks like `[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];` is not getting called. I have the following implemented:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

For some reason if I don't call `[searchDisplayController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];` then the data is not reloaded. Perhaps I am missing a method.

Upon searching it looks like `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` gets called and `tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` is true, but it does not proceed to call `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: So here is why `setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` doesn't work the way I want, it explicitly overrides the original navigation bar: When you return YES to display the search bar in a navigation bar, the system uses the search display controller’s navigationItem property and ignores the navigation item, if set, of the searchContentsController view controller. The displayed search field occupies as much width in the navigation bar as possible.

Comment: I can make it work if I create a new View, add searchBar as a subview, set titleView to the new view and set contentsController to self.navigationController, but the new view completely messes up the display of the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the only way to get it to work is to embed UISearchBar into a UIView, I'm okay with the style now although I have been able to make it exactly the same.